# I compile the below java program in command prompt but it's showing an error and I cannot fix it

Tags: java

I am compiling all my java program in cmd but when I run below program, it's showing an error like `"reached end of file while parsing"` ! And when I try to run it in eclipse it's showing red underline below bold code that is methods and main methods.

```
import java.io.*;

class empl{

    int empno;
    String name;
    String position;
    int ph;

    public void getdata()throws IOException{

        DataInputStream e = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        empno = Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = e.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the employee position: ");
        position=e.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the phone number: ");
        ph = Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

    }

    public void displaydata() {

        System.out.println(empno+"\t"+name+"\t"+position+"\t"+ph);
    }

class manager extends empl{

    int salary;
    String secname;

    public void getdata() throws IOException{
        getdata();

        DataInputStream e= new DataInputStream(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter salary: ");
        salary=Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter second name: ");
        secname= e.readLine();

    }

    public void displaydata(){
        displaydata();
        System.out.println(salary+"\t"+secname);
    }

class inheritt{
    public static void **main(String []args)throws IOException**{

    inheritt e1= new inheritt();         
    inheritt e2= new inheritt();

  **e1.getdata();
    e2.getdata();

    e1.displaydata();
    e2.displaydata();**

}
```

Comment: Your missing the last brace

Comment: What type of error did you get?

Comment: Consider indenting your code sample properly. (It would probably have made at least the brace issue apparent.) Also to highlight errors in a code sample, it's better to use comments. SO won't format code as bold so the asterisks don't stand out and merely give a little bit of extra work to anyone copy-pasting your code to try it out.

Comment: other than missing braces what are those `**` characters in your code ? that seriously gonna give compile time errors

Comment: @user2104603 take a look at my answer, it may solve your problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

Only top level classes can have `static` methods: Declare `inheritt` as a top level class rather than an inner class

```
public class inheritt {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**e1.getdata();
e2.getdata();

e1.displaydata();
e2.displaydata();**
```

`e1` and `e2` are of `inheritt type` and don't have the `getdata()` and `displaydata()` methods

Try this code... I think this may be what you want. I fixed some of the brackets, not really sure of what goes where. I also, made `inheritt extends manager`. I think that's what you want. You may be wanting to show the inheritance chain of the classes.

```
import java.io.*;

class empl{

    int empno;
    String name;
    String position;
    int ph;

    public void getdata()throws IOException{

        DataInputStream e = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        empno = Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = e.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the employee position: ");
        position=e.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the phone number: ");
        ph = Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

    }

    public void displaydata() {
        System.out.println(empno+"\t"+name+"\t"+position+"\t"+ph);
    }
}

class manager extends empl{

    int salary;
    String secname;

     public void getdata() throws IOException{
         getdata();

         DataInputStream e= new DataInputStream(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter salary: ");
         salary=Integer.parseInt(e.readLine());

         System.out.println("Enter second name: ");
         secname= e.readLine();
    }

    public void displaydata(){
        super.displaydata();
        System.out.println(salary+"\t"+secname);
    }

class inheritt extends manager {
    public static void **main(String []args)throws IOException**{

    inheritt e1= new inheritt();         
    inheritt e2= new inheritt();

    e1.getdata();
    e2.getdata();

    e1.displaydata();
    e2.displaydata();

}
```